# SAQL calculate average case close rate for einstein

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

**Scenario**

So I want to display average case closing rate(for now in minute) on dashboard.

**What I've done**

So if I'm not wrong I can calculate the difference time like 
(closed date - created date)

Following is the query I've written

```
q = load "Cases_Data";
q = filter q by 'Status' in ["Closed"];
--q = foreach q generate toDate('ClosedDate_sec_epoch') as 'Closed Date', toDate('CreatedDate_sec_epoch') as 'Created Date',(('ClosedDate_sec_epoch' - 'CreatedDate_sec_epoch')/60) as 'Closed in Hour';
q = foreach q generate avg(('ClosedDate_sec_epoch'-'CreatedDate_sec_epoch')/60) as 'Closed in Hour';
--q = order q by 'Closed in Hour' asc;
q = limit q 2000;
```

It's actually calculating correctly but if I'm calculating an average it's throwing an error

```
Invalid aggregation function args avg('ClosedDate_sec_epoch' - 'CreatedDate_sec_epoch' / #60)
```

I've spend hours trying various things but it seems it's not working(maybe my knowledge is little as I'm new to this).

So please suggest me if this is correct way of doing it or is there any other way which is best than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the difference/rate by adding filed with computeExpression in dataflow, following is the formula

```
date_diff("minute",toDate(ClosedDate_sec_epoch),toDate(CreatedDate_sec_epoch))
```

the field is called **case_close_rate** and now I can calculate avg('case_close_rate') if I want to show it in dashboard/chart.

I don't know if this is proper solution to this or not so can anyone confirm this is good way of solving this?